# How to config NGINX subdomain with 2 react app and node server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I'm a beginner for NGINX and my problem is I has 1 domain and have 2 subdomain. My OS server is Ubuntu 16.04

1. www. + myDomain.com this dns should direct to http://locolhost:5000 (react app)
2. api. + myDomain.com this dns should direct to http://locolhost:6000 (node server)

And this is my config code

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.myDomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
#config node server
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

    root /root/;

    server_name https://api.myDomain.com/;

    location / {
        # node server 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

#config react app
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

    root /root/;


    server_name https:// + www.myDomain.com/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When I go to www.myDomain.com they redirect to react app (localhost:5000) that work fine ,

But when I go to api.myDomain.com they redirect to the same as www.myDomain.com I expect the result that I get should be node server(localhost:6000)

I'm stuck with it several day please help me . 
     Thanks a lot for help and sorry for my bad in english T-T

Comment: The `server_name` directives should just be a server name. For example: `server_name www.example.com;` and `server_name api.example.com;`

Comment: Thanks very much . Can you explain a little bit why server_name shouldn't have https:// ?

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for an introduction to server names.